# Laravel move() is not uploading images everytime

Tags: php, laravel, file

I use code below:

```
$image_name = 'image' . time() . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$destinationFolder = public_path('images');
$request->file('image')->move($destinationFolder, $image_name);
```

but sometime its not working, images are not storing. Im using heroku as host.

Comment: So this uploads sometimes and sometimes not? If that's the case, try checking if it is a names conflict problem

Comment: check the size of the files being uploaded, if they are greater then the maximum allowed they won't be uploaded therefor the issue it is not from the application, it is from php

Comment: Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53937049/copy-image-to-storage-folder/53937237#53937237

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Storage` facade :

```
$path = \Storage::putFile('images', $request->file('image'));
```

Laravel will generate a name automatically, About Storage facade, just see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem). :)

Answer (score 0):

I made function for upload file and if there is no uploaded file do it again till its upload

```
    $imageFile->move($destinationFolder, $fileName);
    if(file_exists(public_path('images') . '/' . $fileName))
       return public_path('images') . '/' . $fileName;
    else
       self::uploadImage($imageFile, $fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the code and it's working fine.

```
    self::$image = $request->file('image');
    self::$imageName = self::$image->getClientOriginalName();
    self::$directory = 'category-images/';
    self::$image->move(self::$directory, self::$imageName);
    return self::$directory.self::$imageName;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).